# Docker - 403 Forbidden PHP Apache Ubuntu 16

Tags: docker, apache

I have ubuntu 16 and I am trying to work with docker by using PHP 7.4 using this article https://linuxhint.com/lamp_server_docker/ .

Everything is working expect from http://localhost:8080/ as it keeps saying "403 Forbidden".

Here below is how my `docker-compose.yaml` looks like. Created a folder and files inside `/var/www/html/docker2`.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web-server:
    build:
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - myapp:/home/user/Desktop/project
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  mysql-server:
    image: mysql:8.0.19
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.0.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql-server
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
volumes:
  mysql-data:  
  myapp:
    external: true
```

As you can see I have created my project at `home/user/Desktop/project` and I have already done `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/Desktop/` and also opened `000-default.conf` by going at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and added below code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/user/Desktop/project
    <Directory /home/user/Desktop/project>
                Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also created `index.php` file at `/home/user/Desktop/project/index.php` and added below code to test.

When I do `docker-compose up -d`, all services getting started .. I am also able to go to my new phpmyadmin with `5000` port `http://my.i.p.address:5000/` but when I am trying to go here `http://localhost:8080/` it keeps saying `403 Forbidden`. I have also set the permission `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/Desktop/` and restarted both apache - `sudo service apache2 restart` and docker - `docker-compose restart` but no luck.

```
<?php 

phpinfo();
?>
```

Can anyone guide me how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have set up your Apache configuration correctly, but the issue might be related to the ownership and permissions of the files and directories inside your project folder.

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Check Ownership:
   Ensure that the files and directories in your project folder are owned by the correct user. Run the following command to change ownership recursively to your user:

   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/user/Desktop/project
   Replace $USER with your actual username.
2. Check Permissions:

Make sure that the permissions are set correctly. Run the following command to set the correct permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/Desktop/project
```

3. Check Apache Logs:

Check the Apache error logs for any specific error messages. You can view the error log using the following command:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Look for any error messages related to permissions or access issues.

4. Apache Configuration Reload:

After making changes to your Apache configuration or file permissions, reload the Apache service to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Alternatively, you can restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

5. Docker Volume Permissions:
   If you are using Docker volumes, ensure that the Docker container has the correct permissions to read from the volume. You may need to adjust the user or group within the Docker container to match the permissions on the host.

After making these changes, try accessing http://localhost:8080 again. If the issue persists, check the Apache error logs for any new error messages, as they can provide valuable information about the problem. Adjust the permissions accordingly until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But I am having these errors after making above changes in apache log. https://paste.ee/p/q56AT#b2R0C42ZQmaa8xrNcpDyEAKegKGGUVcj

Comment: Additionally, I cleared all the apache logs and then stopped `docker-compose stop
` and restarted `docker-compose restart` now my apache logs has no errors but still not started.

Comment: can we set the port to 81 or or something to exclude the port overwrite issue ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to file permissions or configuration settings. You can try the permissions below.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/your/project
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/project
```

create the docker group and add your user:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

and then log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
Have a look at the link below
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: `sudo groupadd docker` .. This is already exists and I have followed your other commands without any error . still its saying these errors in my apache log file. https://paste.ee/p/q56AT#b2R0C42ZQmaa8xrNcpDyEAKegKGGUVcj.

Comment: Additionally, I cleared all the apache logs and then stopped `docker-compose stop
` and restarted `docker-compose restart` now my apache logs has no errors but still not started.

Comment: can we set the port to 81 or or something to exclude the port overwrite issue ? Is it possible ?